# selected item array isn't being cleared upon next save

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

After every attempt of saving the items selected, I would like for that list to be cleared or empty. For example, a user selected one item - selects save. In the console you will view that object that you have selected. Now if you select the other item and select save, you will still see the previous item that was selected within the console. It would be best if after every save, the array was cleared.

First save:

```
selectedMessages
Array(1)
{messageID: 222, message: "text"}
```

Second Save:

```
selectedMessages
Array(2)
{messageID: 222, message: "text"}
{messageID: 331, message: "text Two"}
```

component.ts

```
rMessages: Message[] = [];
  aMessages: Message[] = [];


constructor( 
  public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { 
    this.messageForm = formBuilder.group({
      selectedMessages: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
   }
    save(form){
    console.log(form.value.selectedMessages)
    }

select(rmessage:Message, isChecked: boolean){
    const selectedMessages = <FormArray>this.messageForm.controls.selectedMessages;
    if(isChecked) {
      selectedMessages.push(new FormControl(rmessage));  
    } else {
      let index = selectedMessages.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.messageID == rmessage.messageID);
      selectedMessages.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
buildChecked() {
    const arr = this.rMessages.map(message => {
      console.log(this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID))
      return this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID)
    });
    return this.formBuilder.array(arr);
  }
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="save(messageForm)">
    <ion-list active text-wrap *ngSwitchCase="'received'" >
      <div class="items"> 

    <ion-item *ngFor="let rmessage of rMessages; index as i">
        <ion-label>
          {{rmessage.message}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="select(rmessage, $event.checked)" value="rmessage"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>

      </div>
        <button ion-button full type="submit"  style="font-size:1.8rem">save</button>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

Comment: please show your component and template code for the form

Comment: Ok I've updated the code, Hopefully that's enough info.

Comment: can you show your `select()` method as well in the component?

Comment: ok I've updated the code above to include select()

Comment: How have you registered your form controls in the template? I only see `[formGroup]="messageForm"` the main form group being registered, where is `selectAll` and `selectedMessages` ?

Comment: I removed the select all from this question because it wasn't relevant, I just removed it. As far as the selected messages, I'm returning return this.formBuilder.array(arr); in buildchecked()

Comment: I'm sorry your code still doesn't give full visibility of what happens when. For example, it doesn't tell me when `buildChecked()` gets called. If you can create a reproduction for this, that would be great! So that people don't have to ask for sections missing back and forth.

Comment: Maybe it's just poorly written code, but buildChecked() isn't being called anywhere. It's returning what selectedMessages is looking for in the formbuilder

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you again but if `buildChecked()` is not being called anywhere (then why do you have such a method in the first place) and `selectedMessages` is called within that method and if `selectedMessages` is not declared as part of the original form in the template, then how do you expect them to work as a formControl? Like I said earlier, it's hard to assume when we still don't know the right context in which your component behaves with its methods and properties

Answer (score 0):

To clear a form, you need:

```
selectedMessages.reset()
```

I don't remember well the structure of messageForm  to access to selectedMessages but a console.log will help you.

Comment: I'm still getting back two arrays after the first save. Reset doesn't seem to be doing anything.